# Conflict between NULL value in a DB and DateTime attributes

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

I have a class with a field named `myDateTime` typed as *nullable* `DateTime`, these are the accessor methods:

```
System.DateTime? _MyDateTime;
public System.DateTime? MyDateTime {get; set;}
```

Somewhere else in my code I need to value `MyDateTime` attribute with  the data write inside `myColumn`.

```
MyDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["myColumn"]);
```

The value from `myColumn` can be `NULL` or `DateTime`. Alas if `myColumn` is NULL this code produce an error cause I can't convert a NULL value. Further, I can't write:

```
MyDateTime = System.DBNull.Value;
```

So I don't know how I could handle this issue if `NULL` value is present in that field.
I would avoid the use of a simple object to store the data and I would preserve a sort of attributes typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert from `DBNull.Value` to the null value of `DateTime?`. It may be simplest to write an extension method on `DbDataReader` for that:

```
public static DateTime? GetNullableDateTime(this DbDataReader reader,
                                            string column)
{
    object value = reader[column];
    return value == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?) null : (DateTime) value;
}
```

Then use it as:

```
MyDateTime = myReader.GetNullableDateTime("myColumn");
```

Note that I'm using a cast rather than `Convert.ToDateTime` - you could use the latter if you really want to automatically convert from strings to `DateTime` values etc, but I prefer to be a bit more explicit about that sort of thing. (It's a sign of the schema probably being inappropriate...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tryparse as following...

```
System.DateTime? _MyDateTime;
public System.DateTime? MyDateTime {get; set;}
        if (DateTime.TryParse(myReader["myColumn"], out MyDateTime ))
        {
            //do stuffs if value is parsed successfully
        }
        else
        {

        }
```